# Increase the 10MB message limit on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, outlook

Okay, so I've done everything listed at the following URL:

http://exchangepedia.com/2007/09/exchange-server-2007-setting-message-size-limits.html

and also did fixed the registry settings that max the message limit @ 10mb in the registry of the workstation. i can only post one link, but this fix is found on google using the error message below as the search term.

and I'm still getting "Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit" on the workstation. Any ideas?

EDIT: Also, we're getting this message in Outlook immediately after you click "Open" to attach the file.

EDIT 2: Thank you for your replies. Still having the error message after several days, so assuming Active Directory should update by now, we've been all over the place so haven't had time to check it this week and long holiday break this year, so will give these a try on Monday and answer the question.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the user is inheriting these settings from the server or org? Its possible the limit is set within the users mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

After going through every change in the article, did you restart the Microsoft Exchange Information Store and Microsoft Exchange Transport services? Some changes in Exchange need service restarts in order to kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Give these changes you've made time to replicate through active directory, then close and reopen outlook and retest.

If this still fails, check out this [article](http://tsoorad.blogspot.com/2008/01/outlook-attachment-size-error.html). You should be able to use the steps in the article to make sure the exchange management console is working properly and indeed altering the settings within AD.

I hope that helps.